# Java Compiler keeps saying "error while writing className: className.class (Permission denied)"

Tags: java, web-applications, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, rhel

I'm working on a Tomcat WebApp for my university which enables students to compile their Java codes and see the trace. I'm installing it on a RHEL7 VM. But when I test the compilation function (this one is not implemented by me), the method I'm providing returns this:

```
error while writing className: className.class (Permission denied)
Error on line 1 in className.java
```

I'll show you the method I think is generating this:

```java
public String compileJavaCode(String javaCode, String javaFileName, File workingDir) throws IOException, TimeoutException{

    javax.tools.JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
    this.createJavaFile(javaCode, javaFileName, workingDir);
    JavaFileObject file = new JavaSourceFromString(javaFileName, javaCode);

    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(file);
    compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits).call();

    String diagn = "";
    for ( Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()){
        diagn+=diagnostic.getMessage(null)+"\n";//E.g. cannot find symbol symbol: variable variablename
        diagn+="Error on line "+Long.toString(diagnostic.getLineNumber())+" in "+diagnostic.getSource().toUri();//E.g. Error on line 22 in ClassName.java
    }
       fileManager.close();
       compiler.run(null, null, null, workingDir.getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+javaFileName);
       return diagn;
}
```

Students will see the content of that `diagn` variable as a result for their code submission.

Fun fact is that I manage to get the `className.class` in the `workingDir` directory but I keep getting that error from the `for` cycle above. Could the problem be `compiler.getTask(...).call()`? I mean maybe `compiler.run` is able to generate the .class correctly but the `compiler.getTask(...).call()` is trying to write the .class somewhere else I don't have permission to write in.

P.S. This is a pretty legacy code so please be merciful with it. :)

As asked by @Alexander, this is the content of the Java file:

```java
public class Sommatore {

    public int somma(int i, int j) {
        return i+j;
    }

    public int differenza(int i, int j) {
        return i-j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Too little information so far. What is the contents of 'className.java' file? If you load it to IDE, does it show any errors? Why don't you read it back via 'fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles()' and what happens when you try this instead of 'JavaSourceFromString()'?

Comment: Also: do you get any output from 'compiler.run()'? Please check the logs.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be some valid java source code? I would expect at least `class Something {}`

Comment: @Alexander Fact is that on my machine and on all the collaborator ones, all of this is working pretty fine. I'm experiencing this kind of problem only on the VM the university provided to us.

Comment: @Alexander and the Java file i just appended to the question is the same file we used time ago to test this on local machines.

Comment: If the problem is with a specific installation of Tomcat, then I would check the SecurityManager rules - please check the Tomcat config files.

Comment: @Alexander first of all thanks for your help.
I checked and the compiler.run() has no output. If i try to remove a ';' for example it returns the error correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the user you are using doesn't have the permissions to write to the destination folder. What are the permissions of the workingDir?

> Fun fact is that i manage to get the className.class in the workingDir directory but i keep getting that error from the for cycle above. Could the problem be the compiler.getTask(...).call()? I mean maybe compiler.run is able to generate the .class correctly but the compiler.getTask(...).call() is trying to write the .class somewhere else i don't have permission to write in.

In order to verify if this is true, you could create a folder with open permissions and try.
For example, you could try using as workingDir = /tmp and check what happens.

**EDIT**

I tried to replicate your code:

```
    public class JavaCompiler {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/");
        System.out.println(compileJavaCode(dir));
    }
    public static String compileJavaCode(File workingDir) throws IOException,      TimeoutException {

        javax.tools.JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
      //    this.createJavaFile(javaCode, javaFileName, workingDir);
      //    JavaFileObject file = new JavaSourceFromString(javaFileName, javaCode);

        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager
                .getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/Foo.java"));
//    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(file);
        compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits).call();

        String diagn = "";
        for (Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
            diagn += diagnostic.getMessage(null) + "\n";//E.g. cannot find symbol symbol: variable variablename
            diagn += "Error on line " + Long.toString(diagnostic.getLineNumber()) + " in " + diagnostic.getSource().toUri();//E.g. Error on line 22 in ClassName.java
        }
        fileManager.close();
        compiler.run(null, null, null, workingDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Foo.java");
        return diagn;
    }
}
```

with *Foo.java*

```
public class Foo {

    public int somma(int i, int j) {
        return i+j;
    }

    public int differenza(int i, int j) {
        return i-j;
    }
}
```

There are some changes, but the result should be the same. 
I noticed that the "path" is specified in

```
File workingDir
```

that will be use in

```
compiler.run(null, null, null, workingDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "Foo.java");
```

and in

```
JavaFileObject file = new JavaSourceFromString(javaFileName, javaCode);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = Arrays.asList(file);
```

that in my example:

```
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager
.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/Foo.java"));
```

What contains yours

```
workingDir
```

and "file"?

```
JavaFileObject file = new JavaSourceFromString(javaFileName, javaCode);
```

In my case, are the same.

I tried to execute the code with different users, and if I use an user that isn't able to write in this folder I obtain

```
/tmp/testSO/src/main/java/Foo.java:5: error: error while writing Foo: /tmp/testSO/src/main/java/Foo.class (Permission denied)
public class Foo {
       ^
1 error
error while writing Foo: /tmp/testSO/src/main/java/Foo.class (Permission denied)
Error on line 5 in file:/tmp/testSO/src/main/java/Foo.java
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @DurdenP. I think that's the problem too. I read that compiler.gettask tries to create a .class file in the source folder. Could that be the guilty directory? 
About the workingDir i ended trying with 777 but seems nothing happened...

Comment: I solved specifing the destination directory with the "-d" parameter ti the compiler. Thanks guys